# MYSQL Inner join results is empty

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I need to join 2 tables based on a customer ID.

My tables are Table1 = 'vbq-customers' and Table2 = 'vbq-sales'

The columns of Table1 are : Customer_id | First_name | last_name etc..
The columns of Table2 are : Receipt_nb | receipt_date | receipt_customer_code etc..

I want to join on Customer_id = receipt_customer_code

The result of this query is empty despite the fact that if have checked the presence of similar info to be joined.

```
BEGIN

DROP TABLE `vbq-sales-customers`;
CREATE TABLE `vbq-sales-customers`
AS

(SELECT * 
  FROM `vbq-sales` 
  INNER JOIN  `vbq-customers`
  ON `vbq-sales`.receipt_customer_code=`vbq-customers`.Customer_id

);

END`
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing here?

Comment: Show example data

Comment: If you don't show us table data, we can't say anything for sure.

Comment: OK I am updating my question.

Comment: check all the quotes and nothing it's misspelling, like the last single quote after the "END"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of possibilities. Easiest to explain would be that one (or both) of the tables are empty, contain zero rows.

Or, there are no rows that "match". There aren't any rows in `vbq-sales` that have a value in `receipt_customer_code` table that is equal to a value in the `Customer_id` column of `vbq-customers`.

We don't see the datatype of either of those columns. There could an implicit data conversion going on  <strike>, or we might have fixed length `CHAR` columns of different lengths (which won't be equal.)</strike> (*Doh!* Please excuse my Oracle.)

Without table definitions, we're just guessing.

I strongly recommend you test just the query (i.e. just the plain SELECT statement), before putting it into a CREATE TABLE AS statement. You don't indicate there's any error creating the table, so we'll disregard other reasons the CREATE TABLE might fail.

---

I don't know what's up with the `BEGIN` and `END`. That made it look like this was an anonymous block in Oracle. But the backticks around the identifiers are very MySQL. It's confuzzling collection of syntax there.

If the problem is that the SELECT query is returning zero rows, just debug that. Get rid of all of the CREATE TABLE AS and everything else.

To inspect the actual contents stored in the columns, you can use the HEX() function... then everything, including non-printable characters will be printable characters `0-9A-F`, which you can look at more closely.

I suspect you may just have some unprintable characters in one of the values, e.g. tab `x'09'`, newline `x'0A'`, carriage return `x'0D'`, etc.

Comment: Hi Spencer: Data type is VARCHAR(50). I have queried both table on a value that matches. But the matching line does not show up with my code.

Comment: Does the SELECT run just by itself return any rows? Are you sure there aren't any "hidden" characters (tab, newline, carriage return, etc.) in the  values? Absent an Oracle style DUMP() function, you could use the HEX() function to inspect a value in the columns.... `SELECT HEX(c.customer_id) FROM \`vbq-customers\` WHERE c.customer_id LIKE 'abc%' LIMIT 1`;

Comment: I have tested the query alone, without the CREATE and it works.. but it does not show anything.

Comment: So, then `=` comparison operator isn't returning TRUE for any rows. I suspect one of your columns has "hidden" characters, or a leading space, or something. Pickout a row from each table you think should "match", and use the `HEX()` function to see the values (contents of the column) you think should match. I suspect you will see a difference.

Comment: Spencer, I have run this: SELECT HEX( customer_id ) 
FROM  `vbq-customers` 
WHERE customer_id LIKE  'abc%'
LIMIT 1 
And nothing gets selected.

Comment: Then leave off the `WHERE` clause. The zero rows tells us that the `vbq-customers` table doesn't contain any rows with a `customer_id` column value that starts with 'abc'. I just added a WHERE clause to whittle down the number of rows. We don't need a HEX() dump of every row. If you are *sure* that there's a row that has a `customer_id` value that *matches* the value stored in the `receipt_customer_code` column of the other table, then take a close look at that one value from each row. And compare the HEX() values.

Comment: Spencer, for a few rows, I see '0D' but most of them returns values like: '5556303030303235390D'. What should I do?

Comment: if you know there is a value in both tables then you can use: `select * from (select "sales", receipt_customer_code, sha1(receipt_customer_code) as sha_hash from vbq-sales where receipt_customer_code="blah") der union select * from (select "customers", Customer_id, sha1(Customer_id) as sha_hash from vbq-customers where receipt_customer_code="blah") der2` to show you whether the strings are truely the same. There may be new line characters `\n`, `\r`on the end if these have been loaded incorrectly from a csv etc

Comment: The `x'0D'` (newline character) at the end of the string is going to make that not match a string that doesn't have that same character. Was this table loaded from a file with lines ending in MS style CR+LF? I bet the line terminator was specified as just linefeed character `'\n'` rather than specifying `'\r\n'`. And that `'\r'` character (`x'0D'`) got included as part of the last field in the file. I think the question you asked is answered. **There aren't any rows that have matching values in the two columns.**

Comment: Sorry Tomb, I don't really get the code you wrote. Could you please kindly  update with the exact code I should put?

Comment: This comment chain is spreading far afield of the original question. If you have another question... How did I get x'0D' characters in my column? How do I get rid of x'0D' characters from the end of column values? How can I "match" strings that end in '\r' to strings that don't?  ... please ask another question.

Comment: OK thank you Spencer. I appreciate your insights and help!

Comment: The x'0D' appeared only in 2 rows. I removed them and it still did not work properly. I will change the Load query to add '\r\n' instead of '\n' only and retry.